# codeigniter routing (regex)

Tags: php, regex, codeigniter, routes

I am trying to route a url as follows:

`domain.com/param/some_controller/method/`

*mapped to*

`some_controller::method($param)`

I am not skilled with regular expressions, which i'm fairly certain are necessary, so I would really appreciate it if someone could help get me started?  Or point me to a good tutorial or example?

Comment: Is `domain.com/param/some_controller/method/` the string that's populated into a certain variable? Like, can I assume the `http(s)://` protocol will never be there, and the string will always be in that exact format, or not? (I'm not familiar with CI.)

Comment: @Wiseguy - all of that is handled by CI, and there is also some rewrite rules so the url is _actually_ `domain.com/index.php?param/some_controller/method`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Same effect, but Codeigniter-style:

```
//remember that custom routes need to go _after_ ci's default routes, as they're executed in the order you provide them
$route['default_controller'] = "welcome";
$route['404_override'] = '';
//exception 1 to your regex here
//exception 2 to your regex here
//so on...
$route['(:any)/(:any)/(:any)'] = "$2/$3/$1";
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$route['(:any)/some_controller/method/'] = "some_controller/method/$1";
```

if your param is a number use `(:num)` instead.

in your controller

```
function method($my_param) {
    echo 'my param is '. $my_param;
}
```

an RL example:

```
$route['(:num)/blog/entry/'] = "blog/view/$1";

class Blog extends CI_Controller {

    function view($id) {
         echo 'fetching blog entry no ' . $id;
    }
}
```

your view will look like

view.php

```
<html>
<body>
link to <?= anchor('1/blog/entry/','my first post'); ?>
link to <?= anchor('2/blog/entry/','my second post'); ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a little messy, because there is currently no way to do this with routing without confusing things. You can try this:

```
$route['([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)'] = "$2/$3/$1";
```

BUT what this says is that it will apply to ANY url: this will confuse regular controllers. You are better served adding some prefix to identify requests you should process with this route: for example

```
$route['a/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)'] = "$2/$3/$1";
```

Comment: what if I were to just order all regular controllers above this?  don't they take to the first route that matches?

Comment: Well, if you listed EVERY URL you could possibly get above this, then yes. That seems like it would be a pain for large numbers of URLs but if you only have 5 or 10 or perhaps even 20 it wouldn't be terrible.

Comment: @ Femi - Yea, most likely less than 5, probably only 2 or 3 exceptions to this route!  I will try your method soon